# Conversion of Mat to UIImage from CvVideoCamera

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I am storing frames in real time from a `CvVideoCamera` using the `- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image` delegate method.

After storing the images I average them all into one image to replicate a long exposure shot using this code:

```
Mat merge(Vector<Mat> frames, double alpha)
{
    Mat firstFrame = frames.front();
    Mat exposed = firstFrame * alpha;

    for (int i = 1; i < frames.size(); i++) {

        Mat frame = frames[i];
        exposed += frame * alpha;
    }
    return exposed;
}
```

After getting the averaged image back I convert it back to a UIImage, but the image I get back is in a strange color space, does anyone know how I can fix this?

Conversion code:

```
+ (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    if ( cvMat.elemSize() == 1 ) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    }
    else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData( (__bridge CFDataRef)data );
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate( cvMat.cols, cvMat.rows, 8, 8 * cvMat.elemSize(), cvMat.step[0], colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault );
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease( imageRef );
    CGDataProviderRelease( provider );
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    return finalImage;
}
```

Here is an example(note: the plane in the middle is because I am recording off a computer monitor)
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you display `exposed` without conversion? Maybe it's not a problem of color space but truncation... If your alpha is too low, most pixel values will be zero (e.g. sum of 100 pixels that each have pixel value 10 with alpha = 0.001 you would expect a result of 10 but it will be 0 because 10*0.001=0 for unsigned char result). similarly, if the sum exceeds 255 it will be saturated to 255